# Difference between $object->lol and $object->$lol

Tags: php

I am having a confusion between this two kinds of code and want to know, what is the difference between them:

```
$object->$lol
// and
$object->lol
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php. Of course this is a dupe but I 'm not sure what it is a dupe *of*.

Answer (score 4):

`$object->lol` will points to some property as defined on the object class:

```
class SomeClass {
    public $lol = 'some value';
}

$object = new SomeClass();
echo $object->lol; //will yield 'some value'
```

And `$object->$lol` will point to some property as defined on the object class, but will access the correct property based on the value for `$lol`:

```
class SomeClass {
    public $lol = 'some value';
    public $random = 'random value';
}

$lol = 'random';

$object = new SomeClass();
echo $object->lol; //will yield 'some value'
echo $object->$lol; //will yield 'random value'
```

Answer (score 3):

`$object->lol` access a instance variable named `lol` on the `$object` object.

`$object->$lol` access a instance variable that has the name contained in the `$lol` variable. It is also accessd on the `$object` object.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, it works the same as the following:

```
$var  = "var2";
$var2 = "hello world";
echo $$var; // This returns "hello world"
```

So, I assume that $object->$lol gets you the variable with the name of your $lol variable.

[Here is some more info about this...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#example-106)

Comment: No, it isn't: "Variable variable" != "variable property access"

Answer (score 2):

First one is like

```
$lol = 'foo';
$object->{$lol} == $object->foo;
```

Second one is regular property access.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain you this,look this code:

```
<?php
$var1->"hello";
$var2->$var1;
?>
```

If we do a print or an echo $var1 will show "hello" but in $var2 we will see "hello" again because $var1 and $var2 are the same.

In the second code:

```
<?php
$var1->"hello";
$var2->"var1";
?>
```

Now we print $vare1 and it'll show "hello" but $var2 will show "var1".I hope this help you to solve your problem.